# How to set column width in Kendo Grid

Tags: angularjs, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, bootstrap-4

I have to set some fixed column width in Kendo Grid which has no column headers.That means I get data simlar to below with single column "foo_data" and am hiding this column header and showing in the kendo Grid as is.The columns and rows in the Grid are dynamic ie.in the below example there are 9  columns  and 6 rows sometimes I may get 3 columns and 5 rows. I am using Kendo Ui,Angularjs and bootstrap frameworks.I want *more space between columns* in the Grid.How can I achieve this ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
var foo_data= [{"1 AAA BBB CCC 44444444444444444 555555555555555555 67777777777777777 333333333333333  99999999999"},
               "2  AAA BBB CCC 44444444444444444 555555555555555555 67777777777777777 333333333333333  99999999999"},
               "3  AAA BBB CCC 44444444444444444 555555555555555555 67777777777777777 333333333333333  99999999999"},
               "4  AAA BBB CCC 44444444444444444 555555555555555555 67777777777777777 333333333333333  99999999999"},
               "5  AAA BBB CCC 44444444444444444 555555555555555555 67777777777777777 333333333333333  99999999999"},
               "6  AAA BBB CCC 44444444444444444 555555555555555555 67777777777777777 333333333333333  99999999999"}];
```

**Hiding column header in the Kendo Grid:**

```
columns: [{
    field: "foo_data",
    headerAttributes: {
           style: "display; none"
    }
```

Comment: if you find the answer beneficial, don't forget to vote or accept the answer

Comment: From what I understand, your data is actually an array with only one dimension (as opposed to two, which is common for data grids), in which every entry represents an entire row. Also, you're not changing the structure in anyway before you present the data to the kendo grid), which means your grid, in fact, has only ONE column! So, what you actually need is just more space between the chunks of data inside the one cell you have in each row of the grid. Am I getting it right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `width` in column array in kendo grid. Look at the below code.

```js
 columns: [{
        field: "foo_data",
        headerAttributes: {
               style: "display; none"
        },
        width: 175
```

the `width` is in pixels.it will increase the column width to 175 pixels

Comment: I am not sure if you guys understood my question as I said in my original question that I get all the data (unstructured) in a single column.In other words, I have all the data in a single column and  I want some space between columns. I am already aware of above answers but my context here is different.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it as shown in below code. For more information refer [kendo UI documentation (Grid / AngularJS)](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular)

```
 $scope.mainGridOptions = {
            dataSource: {
                type: "odata",
                transport: {
                    read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Employees"
                },
                pageSize: 5,
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true
            },
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            dataBound: function() {
                this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
            },
            columns: [{
                field: "FirstName",
                title: "First Name",
                width: "120px"
                },{
                field: "LastName",
                title: "Last Name",
                width: "120px"
                },{
                field: "Country",
                width: "120px"
                },{
                field: "City",
                width: "120px"
                },{
                field: "Title"
            }]
        };
```